# python move item to another location

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list in python3

```
l = [31,22,63,44,15]
```

and I want to move an element to a different location in the list:

```
move(31,3)
l = [22,63,44,31,15]
```

what is the most elegant way to do so?

Comment: What happens if the items are not unique?

Comment: @DeepSpace items are unique

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to find the index of the element, remove it, and insert it at the new position:

```
l.insert(3, l.pop(l.index(31)))
```

But this can be quite inefficient, as removing and inserting are somewhat expensive operations.

Comment: and what will be a more efficient way?

Comment: @oren_isp I don't know one. There is no one efficient way to do it. Whether it's efficient or not depends on the index of the element and where you're moving it.